# SAS locate country from the address string?

Tags: sas

I have a list of customer addresses in a dataset where I am trying to locate the Country of residence, for example: `NEWSOUTHWALESAUSTRALIA` could be indexed to report the country as Australia. I am trying to use the do loop approach to scan through the list of 252 Countries to relate the Country of residence from a dataset called address_format

The dataset test has the list of 252 Countries which have upcased & compressed, as has the field `concat_address, so should no issues with differences in the text.`

```
%macro counter;
%do ii = 1 %to 252;

data test;
                set country_data (obs=&ii.);
                call symput('New_upcase_country',trim(New_upcase_country));
                country_new = compress(trim(country_two));
                call symput('country_new',trim(country_new));

run;

data ADDRESS_FORMAT_NEW;
               set ADDRESS_FORMAT;
                     length success $70.;
                     format success $70.; 
                 if index(concat_address,"&country_new.") ge 1 
                     then do ;           
                country="&country_new.";                
                end;
run;

%end;
%mend;
%counter;
```

For some odd reason If I manually programme `if index(concat_address,'AUSTRALIA')`, I get results, but inside the macro the results are blank.

Is there something obvious I am missing that is preventing the success of the country index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `obs=` option can be thought of as `lastobs=` (there is no lastobs option).

The option for skipping the first n-1 observations is `firstobs=`

This example will yield 4 rows (8-5+1)

```
data class;
  set sashelp.class (firstobs=5 obs=8);
run;
```

So you want

- `firstobs=&ii obs=&ii`, or
- `firstobs=&ii` and a `STOP;RUN;`
   to prevent going to row `&ii+1` and beyond.

Despite the above answer, I would recommend switching to a **no macro** approach that does all 252 checks in one data step (versus one step per check). There are numerous ways of doing such, here is one way that **does not** use arrays or hashes

For example:

```
data have;
input;
text = _infile_;
datalines;
BONGOBONGOAUSTRALIA
SOMEWHERE IN CHINA
CANADA USA
TIBET LANE, NORWAY
run;

data countries;
length name $50;
input;
name = _infile_;
datalines;
AUSTRALIA
GERMANY
UNITED STATES
TIBET
NORWAY
run;
```

Output only first match.  An important code feature is using `point=` and `nobs=` options on the `set` statement inside the `do` loop.

```
data want;
  set have;
  do index = 1 to check_count until (found);
    set countries point=index nobs=check_count;
    found = index(text,trim(name));
    if found then matched_country = name;
  end;
run;
```

Output all matches

```
data want (keep=text matched_country);
  set have;
  do index = 1 to check_count;
    set countries point=index nobs=check_count;
    found = index(text,trim(name));
    if found then do;
      found_count = sum(found_count,1);
      matched_country = name;
      output;
    end;
  end;
  if not found_count > 0 then do;
    matched_country = '** NO MATCH **';
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: Be sure to also review the SAS literature on fuzzy matching. Good start "How to perform a fuzzy match using SAS functions" https://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2015/01/27/how-to-perform-a-fuzzy-match-using-sas-functions/

Comment: Thanks Richard! I'll look into it. :)